# Xamarin ListView not appearing

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin

I'm trying to make a simple list application in xamarin forms using data binding but the data doesn't appear.
Here's my MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Practice3"
             x:Class="Practice3.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Films}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell
                    Text="{Binding Title}" 
                    TextColor="Black"
                    Detail="{Binding Resume}" 
                    DetailColor="Gray"
                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Practice3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Film> Films { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Films = new ObservableCollection<Film>{
                new Film{
                    Title = "X-Men (2000)",
                    Resume = "Two mutants come to a private academy for their kind whose resident superhero team must oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers."
                },
                new Film{
                    Title = "X-Men 2 (2003)",
                    Resume = "The X-Men band together to find a mutant assassin who has made an attempt on the President's life, while the Mutant Academy is attacked by military forces."
                },
                new Film{
                    Title = "X-Men: The last stand (2006)",
                    Resume = "When a cure is found to treat mutations, lines are drawn amongst the X-Men, led by Professor Charles Xavier, and the Brotherhood, a band of powerful mutants organized under Xavier's former ally, Magneto."
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And Films.cs

```
namespace Practice3
{
    public class Film
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Resume { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to just put a Label in the StackLayout and it appeared clearly, but the ListView seems to be empty or invisible.

Comment: Do you implement INPC? you should create a separate MainPageViewModel.cs...

Comment: you need to set your BindingContext: this.BindingContext = this;

Comment: @Jason it's not implied?

Comment: no, typically you would bind to a VM and the page has no way of knowing what your VM is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it this way:
MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Practice3"
             x:Class="Practice3.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="FilmList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell
                    Text="{Binding Title}" 
                    TextColor="Black"
                    Detail="{Binding Resume}" 
                    DetailColor="Gray"
                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Practice3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Film> Films { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Films = new ObservableCollection<Film>{
                new Film{
                    Title = "X-Men (2000)",
                    Resume = "Two mutants come to a private academy for their kind whose resident superhero team must oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers."
                },
                new Film{
                    Title = "X-Men 2 (2003)",
                    Resume = "The X-Men band together to find a mutant assassin who has made an attempt on the President's life, while the Mutant Academy is attacked by military forces."
                },
                new Film{
                    Title = "X-Men: The last stand (2006)",
                    Resume = "When a cure is found to treat mutations, lines are drawn amongst the X-Men, led by Professor Charles Xavier, and the Brotherhood, a band of powerful mutants organized under Xavier's former ally, Magneto."
                }
            };
            FilmList.ItemsSource = Films;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that works, but as I noted above simply assigning the BindingContext for your page should have solved it too

Comment: True, I just didn't saw your answer until I had it solved. Thank you.